# How to write while members of class still exist in page condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery or js, preferably jQuery or js that is well supported, how can I do a while with the condition that there are still members of the class on the page.

What I am doing in the suite of the while is systematically removing the elements in the class, but I can not remove them all at once.

Let's say the class is `.card`.

Here is my code:

```
$('#dismissAllButton').click(function(){
    while($('.dataCard').length>0){
        $('.right').eq(0).remove();
        $('#left').children('.dataCard').first().addClass('animated').addClass('right');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.right').eq(0).remove();
            $('#right').children('.dataCard').first().addClass('animated').addClass('right');
        }, 150);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <div class="dataCard"></div>
    <div class="dataCard"></div>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div class="dataCard"></div>
    <div class="dataCard"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest that any time an element is removed, check `$('.card').length`

Comment: Looks like an XY problem

Comment: What is an XY problem?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I think you'll need to post your code.

Comment: @JasonP I updated the question with my code. I'm trying to remove all `.dataCard`s systematically from a left column, then a right column, then repeat. `.right` is a css animation, animating it out.

Comment: You don't need a while loop.

Comment: Can you provide more context to your code? maybe some html?

Comment: @KevinB I updated the question with the basic DOm structure.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what effect you are going for? You click the button, and, exactly what happens? the cards in left fade out 1 by 1? the cards in right fade out 1 by 1? what? Your code as is clearly doesn't work, so it's difficult to understand what you're going for by the code provided. *"systematically"* doesn't tell us anything about how you want them to be removed.

Comment: @KevinB Oh, I'm sorry. A `.dataCard` from left moves to the right, then a `.dataCard` from right moves to the right. Then back to left and then back to right and so on as long as there are `.dataCard`s

Comment: So, you want to remove one from left, then right, and repeat until there are none left? are there always the same number in left and right?

Comment: I threw this together, but after reading your most recent comments, I don't think it's what you're looking for. Might give you an idea on where to go though: http://jsfiddle.net/VSjcS/

Comment: @KevinB Yes. No, there could be 1 in each or only 1 in left only. Or the same in both.

Comment: @JasonP It is interesting. I learned from the code. Thank you.

Comment: Is this anywhere in the ballpark of the effect you're going for? http://jsfiddle.net/5wRG9/1/ (updated fiddle) Here's another with a slight delay between the lists: http://jsfiddle.net/5wRG9/2/

Comment: @KevinB Yes, the second one. Please put that as the answer so I can choose it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a while loop. Instead, first iterate over each list, then within each list, iterate over each card. This allows you to set a delay on removing the card based on which list it is in so that you can get the effect of removing 1 by 1 from each list at the same time.

```
$("#dismissAllButton").on("click", function() {
    $("#left, #right").each(function(i){
        $(".dataCard",this).each(function(ii) {
            var card = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                card.addClass("right");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    card.remove();
                },500);
            }, i*250+ii*500); // adjust `250` and `500` as needed.
        });
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5wRG9/2/)

`250` is the delay between left and right, and `500` is the animation duration (dont forget to also update the css transition to reflect that)

Answer (score 1):

while length isn't 0 remove.

```
while ($(".card").length) {
   $(".card").eq(0).remove();
}
```

Comment: what does `.eq()` do?

Comment: It is creating an infinite loop or something. The page gets stuck. I'm doing this on click of a button, let's call it #button.

Comment: You now know how to do it, try to make it work ? Try  `while($(".card").length != 0)` or `undefined` with `typeof`

Comment: I updated the question with my code. I'm trying to remove all .dataCards systematically from a left column, then a right column, then repeat. .right is a css animation, animating it out

Comment: okay, let me try that. I changed it with `>0`, but that didn't work. Thank you. I'll try the other things.

Comment: From your code, it seems that you'll always have `.dataCard` class since you remove only the `.right` class even if `.left` contains `.dataCard` too.